# What is the name of tool that gives you the declaration of a function in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ide

Just a simple question about definitions in C/C++ toolchains and IDE's:
What is the name of tool/mechanism/software that direction you to the declaration of the function like when, for example: You are in a Eclipse based IDE and press "CTRL + Left Mouse Button" on a function name and you are directioned to the function declaration.

Is that the Linker? Or the Intellisense? Or maybe another thing?

**EDIT**:
PS: Not just a function, but also a define, a typedef, a class and so on.

Comment: I think it's Intellisense. It gets information about functions, variables, etc.

Comment: In Eclipse it's "Indexer".

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh. , did you know if it have the same name in others IDE's? Like in Netbeans for example?

Comment: In emacs it's etags.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a "go to definition" feature, or just "code navigation" tools.

Comment: Different IDEs call it different things, e.g., Visual Studio calls it Intellisense. The generic term for it is 'auto-completion'. **EDIT** Oops, I misread the question, I thought you were referring to the tool which automatically inserts code based on a partial match. Still, the basic statement that it is called different things stands.

Comment: There are many different tools. `ctags`, `cscope` - these can be integrated with many IDEs/code editors.

Comment: No formal name.

Comment: In VSC there's the "C/C++ Extension Pack" which gives many features including this "go to definition " feature, it provides tools like CMake, Doxygen docs , syntax formatting (i believe) and many more

Comment: In notepad++ there's the gtags plugin

Comment: In IAR Electronic Workbench IDE, you can right click on an identifier and then select either "Go to declaration" or "Go to definition".

Comment: In Xcode, it's called Code Sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, like said in comments the name of this tool depends of each IDE. But it could be described in general  words as " 'go to definition' feature"